# How can I use tensorflow 1.14 on RTX 3080?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using RTX 3080 graphic cards.Amper cards only support CUDA 11.0,or higher version.The matching tensorflow version is 2.x.And I need to run code on tensorflow 1.14.How can I do that on RTX 3080?

Comment: All you need is to upgrade your codebases. Returining to tf 1.x is a bad idea, IMO.

Comment: how to upgrade codebases?Do you mean changing code to fit tf 2.x?

Comment: Hi @rayhathorn777, please refer to this [documentaion](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for migrating your code from 1.x to 2.x. Thank You.